# Can we insert tables in google cloud monitoring dashboards?

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I am creating a dashboard with Google Cloud Monitoring. We can insert charts in the dashboard, but I dont see how we can show data in tabular format via UI.

[image]

Comment: there is a "legend" section below the chart, it show data in tabular format (albeit only the metadata and the MOST RECENT data points).

Comment: It combines all metrics into one column. Can we separate them into different columns?

Comment: To get some more idea about the monitoring chart, you can have a look to these documentations. [Document #1](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/chart-view-options?&_ga=2.90827550.-52852610.1588284997&_gac=1.178504336.1592858475.EAIaIQobChMI4feD_6OW6gIVj4bACh0j3waJEAAYASAAEgJp4_D_BwE#using-statistics-mode) and [Document #2](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector?&_ga=2.28126648.-52852610.1588284997&_gac=1.242544182.1592858475.EAIaIQobChMI4feD_6OW6gIVj4bACh0j3waJEAAYASAAEgJp4_D_BwE#the_metric-specification_field)